# Serializing struct to char * and sending it over UDP

Tags: c++, sockets

I am exchanging a struct called `struct update_packet` with other servers (of identical or similar system) running the same program through UDP socket using sendto(..) and recvfrom().

Based on answers from stackoverflow.com/questions/27055729/, I wrote a function to serialize `struct update_packet`

```
struct update_packet {
    uint16_t num_update_fields;
    uint16_t port;
    uint32_t IP;

    vector<struct node> nodes;

    const char * serialize() const {
        ostringstream oss;
        put_u16_as_big(oss, num_update_fields);
        put_u16_as_big(oss, port);
        put_u32_as_big(oss, IP);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < num_update_fields; ++i) {
            put_u32_as_big(oss, nodes[i].IP);
            put_u16_as_big(oss, nodes[i].port);
            put_u16_as_big(oss, nodes[i].nil);
            put_u16_as_big(oss, nodes[i].server_id);
            put_u16_as_big(oss, nodes[i].cost);
        }
        string str = oss.str();

        cout << str << "\t" << str.size() << endl;
        cout << str.data() << "\t" << sizeof(str.data()) << endl;
        return str.data();
    }
                       ...
};
```

and `put_u16_as_big` is a helper function that puts a `uint16_t` in Big Endian to a referenced `ostringstream`.

```
void put_u16_as_big(ostringstream& oss, uint16_t data) {
    if (is_big_endian()) {
        oss.write((const char *)&data, sizeof(data));
    }
    else {
        const char * ptr = (const char *)&data;
        unsigned int s = sizeof(data);
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < s; ++i) {
            oss.put(ptr[s-1-i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it is instantiated like

```
struct update_packet up;
const char * up_to_send = up.serialize();
```

and sent.

I put some `cout` in `serialize()` for testing.

With

```
cout << str << "\t" << str.size() << endl;
```

It prints weird looking characters (numbers in a box) and the size is 44.

However, with `str.data()` which returns `const char *`

```
cout << str.data() << "\t" << sizeof(str.data()) << endl;
```

I get

```
    8
```

empty string for `str.data()` and 8 for size

Moreover, when I receive the data through UDP socket and print the return value from `recvfrom` which is the byte received, it prints 0, and the received message is the same kind as that weird looking character, but only one character.

What is the problem, and how can I fix this so that I could receive and retrieve data on the receiving side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `put_u16_as_big()`, you're writing raw binary data into a `ostringstream` (a string) without actually converting it to a string.  If you want to write raw binary data you need to write to a basic `ostream`.

Also since you're not actually converting it to a string you can't print it out as though it were a string.

If you insist on using `ostringstream` then instead of using `oss.put()` and `oss.write()` which will insert raw binary you should use `operator<<`which will insert formatted output.  Of course if you're really using strings then endianness doesn't matter.

Comment: Big Endianness is required by the project specification. How can I write to `ostringstream` in Big Endian and read it at receiving end if it uses little endian?

Comment: @user2418202 if you're converting it to a string representation of the number then you'll be 'shedding' the endianness.  Endianness is something that is intrinsic to the in memory binary representation of the number.  If you want to send raw binary data then you should send it in "network byte order" which is big endian.  THere are a bunch of C library functions that will convert numbers from host byte order to network byte order and back: `htonl()`, `ntohl()` for `long`s and there are ones for `short`s as well.  Raw binary and string representations both have pros and cons...